# awk extended pattern matching (embedding pattern matching in actions for already matched strings)

Tags: awk, string, patterns, regular-expression

I want handle strings of the form:

```
PREFIX_TYPE_N,DATA
```

So, does the *awk (gawk, mawk, nawk) support including pattern matching in the action for already matched string? Something like this (of course, doesn't work for me):

```
*awk 'BEGIN { FS="," }
     /PREFIX/ {
                /TYPE_1/  {printf "[TYPE1] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- included pattern 
                /TYPE_2/  {printf "[TYPE2] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- another included pattern
                ...                                        // <-- some more included patterns
              }' "filename"
```

Or do I still need if/else or switch/case?

Comment: Same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283412/awk-extended-pattern-matching-embedding-pattern-matching-in-actions-for-already) one.

Comment: [Don't crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but I'm not an expert of awk so there might be better answers if you wait:

```
*awk 'BEGIN { FS="," }
     /PREFIX/ {
                if ($0 ~ /TYPE_1/)  {printf "[TYPE1] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- included pattern 
                if ($0 ~ /TYPE_2/)  {printf "[TYPE2] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- another included pattern
                ...                                        // <-- some more included patterns
              }' "filename"
```